# dropzone.js not reading selected file

Tags: php, dropzone.js, dropzone

Dropzone.js is not reading selected file while I am trying to print file name although file is uploading in upload directory.

Here is my code:

**index.php**

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" method="post" id="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="fallback">
                    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" multiple="" />
                </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
            </form>
```

**upload.php**

```
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

echo $target_file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $status = 1;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Undefined index: file

I am using latest version of dropzonejs, i.e 5.2.0

**Edit**

File is uploading if I remove this from form:

```
<div class="fallback">
  <input name="file" type="file" id="file" multiple="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is there something inside `$_FILES`? Check with `var_Dump($_FILES)`

Comment: Could you paste your JS ?

Comment: Var_dump the $_POST and make sure everything is there....

Comment: var_Dump is showing null, but files are uploading to the directory.

Comment: Post your related JS

Comment: no any js in index.php or upload.php. only cdn of dropzone is included - <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.2.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>.

Comment: Any JS error in Developer Console? Sometimes Dropzone auto discovery does not work well.

Comment: No, not any js error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved this by adding id to submit button and placing it outside of form and adding some js.

**index.php**

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
<button id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
```

*js*

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

  autoProcessQueue: false,

  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.

  }
};
```